# Water pressure needle broken?

Tags: plumbing, water, water-pressure

The needle on my water pressure has moved beyond the maximum measure, and I haven't checked it in several weeks. Does this mean it is broken, or do I need to let some pressure escape?

The inbound mains supply is not of a particularly high pressure given that I live in a remote area.

[image: water pressure needle]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Let some pressure escape" would be happening every time you open a tap downstream of your pressure limiting device (regulator), if there is one on the system. That pressure reading (which is quite high, by the way) means one of the following:

- your pressure limiting device (regulator) has failed and your mains pressure is currently quite high
- the pressure gauge has failed
- your pressure limiting device (regulator) has failed and there was a period of time that your mains pressure was high, but downstream pressure has not yet been relieved.

Comment: Thank you for this answer Jimmy, very helpful. Can I ask - do you think there is a hazard here that requires an emergency call-out? Will this level of pressure burst pipes?

Comment: A "BAR" is equal to one atmosphere (approx. 14.7 pounds per square inch), so 10 BAR is roughly 147 p.s.i. Quite high for residential plumbing system. My intuition tells me that your gauge is broken. If your pressure were that high you would notice it (and things would be starting to leak).